# When applying media queries, nothing is getting adjusted

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm extremely confused because I am pretty certain that I have it set up correctly. It doesn't set the font to 10 pixels on my phone and when I adjust the screen. Am I missing something?
Here's the code:

```
.above-email-box {
  /* aligns text to the center with position absolute */
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 90px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: 'Glory', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Klee One', cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
}
@media only screen (min-width: 768px) {
  .above-email-box {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: this happen when your device is phone? what about laptop or desktop?

Comment: @media only screen and (min-width: 768px){ Your Styles} // when you use only yo u have to use and to define what the screen size will be

Comment: @SuneelKumar I tried to adjust it on my phone and adjusting my desktop's width.

Comment: @kiran I have tried that and sadly it doesn't work.

Comment: @icantfindmyspider, I put a solution, Hope it will help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.above-email-box {
  /* aligns text to the center with position absolute */
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 90px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: 'Glory', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Klee One', cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .above-email-box {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="above-email-box"> Demo Text</div>
```

**Logical operators**

[The logical operators not, and, and only can be used to compose a complex media query. You can also combine multiple media queries into a single rule by separating them with commas.](http://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#logical_operators)

You have to define `max-width` & `min-width` consciously, sometime it can be confusing, `min-width` means when you add styles into it, it display the styles after the `min-width` condition is met, if you define `min-width:500px` your styles are applicable on screens width 500px and above not below

Answer (score 2):

In order to run the media query for mobile device you need to change `min-width` to `max-width` like below

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .above-email-box {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}
```

When your screen width is below `768px` it will change `font-size` to `10px`